# Creating a rolling mean of an annual cycle in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, cycle, rolling-computation

I am trying to use pandas to create a rolling mean, but of an annual cycle (so that the rolling mean for 31st December would take into account values from January, and the rolling means for January would use values for December). Does anyone know if there is a built in or other elegant way to do this?

The only way I've come up with so far is to create the annual cycle and then repeat it over leap years (as the annual cycle includes the 29th Feb), take the rolling mean (or standard deviation, etc) and then crop the middle year. There must be a better solution! Here's my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import calendar

data = np.random.rand(366)
df_annual_cycle = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['annual_cycle'],
    index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01','2004-12-31').strftime('%m-%d'),
    data=data
)

df_annual_cycle.head()

#        annual_cycle
# 01-01      0.863838
# 01-02      0.234168
# 01-03      0.368678
# 01-04      0.066332
# 01-05      0.493080

df1 = df_annual_cycle.copy()
df1.index = ['04-'+x for x in df1.index]
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index,format='%y-%m-%d')
df2 = df.copy()
df2.index = ['08-'+x for x in df2.index]
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index,format='%y-%m-%d')
df3 = df.copy()
df3.index = ['12-'+x for x in df3.index]
df3.index = pd.to_datetime(df3.index,format='%y-%m-%d')

df_for_rolling = df1.append(df2).append(df3)
df_rolling = df_for_rolling.rolling(65).mean()
df_annual_cycle_rolling = df_rolling.loc['2008-01-01':'2008-12-31']
df_annual_cycle_rolling.index = df_annual_cycle.index
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pandas.DataFrame.rolling()`.
Details and other rolling methods can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Let's assume we have a dataframe like so:

```
data = np.concatenate([
    1*np.random.rand(366//6), 
    2*np.random.rand(366//6), 
    3*np.random.rand(366//6), 
    4*np.random.rand(366//6), 
    5*np.random.rand(366//6), 
    6*np.random.rand(366//6)
])

df_annual_cycle = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['annual_cycle'],
    index=pd.date_range('2004-01-01','2004-12-31').strftime('%m-%d'),
    data=data,
)
```

We can do:

```
# reset the index to integers:
df_annual_cycle = df_annual_cycle.reset_index()

# rename index column to date:
df_annual_cycle = df_annual_cycle.rename(columns={'index':'date'})

# calculate the rolling mean:
df_annual_cycle['rolling_mean'] = df_annual_cycle['annual_cycle'].rolling(32, win_type='triang').mean()

# plot results
df_annual_cycle.plot(x='date', y=['annual_cycle', 'rolling_mean'], style=['o', '-'])
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion. I don't quite see how it is creating a rolling mean (as in each date is replaced by the mean of, say the 65 days surrounding the date, 32 days before and 32 after).

Comment: I see - what I provided is the mean calculated based on all the previous dates (same way `cumsum()` works). Let me see if I can edit my answer to address your request.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and be sure to let me know if you have any questions or need anything else.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks again for your work on this. The issue I have is getting the rolling mean of an annual cycle. Because it is an annual cycle, the 1st of January is "next to" the 31st December. So in your example above, the first few rolling mean values for the beginning of the year (missing in your plot, in the orange line), ought to be taking information from the data at the end of the year to create the rolling mean. Essentially, I want to find a way to tell pandas that the data is 'circular' rather than linear in time.

Comment: @user12938030 I'm not sure if there's a "proper" way to do that, but a workaround might be to repeat your last few rows to the top of your dataframe. A bit clunky but works.